# Javascript Functions excercise - "" sign

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I've just proceeded to Javascript Functions and have a basic question to you guys. I've created a function defining a variable 'foodDemand' that is a function with declared list of operations : printing out sentence "I want to eat" and the parameter of the function specified when calling this function on another line.

```
 var foodDemand = function (food) {
        console.log ("I want to eat" + "" + food);
    }

    foodDemand("Ice cream")
```

I have a particular question. What ' "" ' stands for ? What does it do ? Theoretically "I want to eat" + food (foodDemand's function parameter) should do the trick, right ? Please can somebody explain to me this tiny detail ? I'm just a beginner that wants to drill enough deep to have no doubts on anything before proceeding to next excercices. Thank you for any help ! Danny

Comment: it's supposed to be " " and that would just add space between words, otherwise that would stick together "I want to eatIce cream"

Comment: So it's just an additional string literal that add's space after the first string and defined function parameter ? :). I would achieve the same effect after writing for example "I want to eat " (With a space before the ending quotation symbol), right ?

Comment: Yup :) that would do the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"..."` are [String Literals](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.4).

`""` is just an empty string.
It is used for forcing the convertion to strings in some special cases, but it is **not** necessary in your case.

---

I think that you actually want `" "` with a space in it. Otherwise *eat* and *Ice cream* would stick together in the output.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick answer ! I think that I understood well. However, can you please provide me with some sample and basic function with "..." being used in it ? I would like to understand when I need to use it and when I don't. Thanks ! :)

Comment: @Danny_Student Everytime you want to define a string, you use a String Literal. In your code, `"Ice cream"` is also a string (it defines a new String object).

Comment: Ok, got it :). So in my case I can resign from using that "" in the middle between "I want to eat" string and "food" function parameter ?

Comment: @Danny_Student Yes, you can.